# Using CURL - Post and redirect help

Tags: php, post, curl

I've been banging my head against a wall for a few hours now - and it's probably something really obvious I've missed!

I'm trying to connect to a payment service provider (PSP) using CURL, post data and follow the post so the user actually ends up on the PSP's site.

Using the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://psp.com/theirpage');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,  "http://mysite.com/mypage");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This successfully connects, verifies the data I've passed, but instead of redirecting the user to the PSP, it just loads the HTML on my site. Safe mode is off, and open_basedir is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of redirection are you expecting to happen? A header redirect issued by them will be seen (and followed) only by curl, not your user's browser

Comment: I think curl reads html page content. you need to look for any alternative

Comment: you should consider using their API ( if they offer ) .

Comment: Thanks guys - intially I thought that was the case, but the 'followlocation' option had be confused!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURL would do an internal redirect and it wont have any effect on the user viewing your curl script. Keep in mind that the payment was made by your server NOT the users computer, hence expecting the session to work for the user is incorrect. cURL 'is the browser'.

If you just want a redirect after payment is made via cURL, you will have to do it via `header()` or by using some JS like `window.location`.

Answer (score 0):

The `curl` request is being made from your server, and as such your server is receiving the response page. There's no way to initiate the request from the server and have the client receive the response. Either return the HTML to the user from your site (as you're doing), or make the request from the client's browser using Javascript. Hope that helps